# document.getElementById() is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to the forum and new to html. I've tried may of the answers in the forums but nothing is seaming to work. While like I said i'm new I've tried looking through w3shools and having a hard time figuring this out.

what I want is to when I click the button, I would like is for it to look at the `<h1><h1>` and are you = x, if you are = to x then please change to work. if you are = to work please change to x.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Head>
<title>Heather I Love You!</title>
</head>
<body style= background-color:#A8A8A8>


<!========This is the header===========>
<div id="header" style= "background-color:#00FF33;" >
<h1><p id="hheader">Heather this is a series of Pitures, Videos, and Poems to 

show you the love that I have for you!"</p></h1></div>

<!=============The side bar that will allow a list of where she Wants to 

go==========>

<div id="Menu" Style="background-

color:#660033;height:300px;width:125px;float:left;">
<Talbe>

<b><h3{color:white}>Categories</h3></b><br>
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeHead()">click here!</button><br>



<!--Functions-->
<Script>
function ChangeHead()
{
var g=document.getElementById("hheader")
  x="Heather this is a series of Pitures, Videos, and Poems to show you the 

love that I have for you!"
  work="Here are some pictures of us and the boys"
  if (document.getElementById("hheader").innertext == x)
    {
    document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML= =work; 
    }
  else
    {
    document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML== x
    }
}
</Script>
</body>

</Html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to. Are those line breaks in the definition of `x` in the actual code? You're not allowed to have line breaks inside strings in JavaScript.

Comment: You should show the related HTML. If id="hheader" does not exist in the DOM then this may be the issue.

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply, Like I said before I am new to this. I've been creating this in notepad and I don't know what the java script console is. please advise.

Comment: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners

Comment: You can hit F12 to get the console. Also, when assigning variables use `=` not `==`, which is used to check for equality.

Comment: `<h3{color:white}>` is invalid HTML btw.

Comment: `<!=== This is an invalid comment format ===>` you should `<!-- use this correct format, instead -->`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an element with the id 'hheader':

```
<div id='hheader'>Heather this is a series of Pitures, Videos, and Poems to show you the love that I have for you!</div>
```

The following script should work:

```
<script>
    function ChangeHead() {
  var g = document.getElementById("hheader");
  var x = "Heather this is a series of Pitures, Videos, and Poems to show you the love that I have for you!";
  var work = "Here are some pictures of us and the boys";

  if (document.getElementById("hheader").innerText == x) {
    document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML = work; 
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML = x;
  }
};
ChangeHead();
</script>
```

So that the script will change the text of the 'hheader' div to the value of the `work` variable

I've found a few syntax errors in your code and I corrected them accordingly.

Here you can see a working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/LvcCe/

Comment: FireFox uses `textContent` rather than `innerText` so a better cross-browser approach is `var text = x.innerText || x.textContent`. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07

Comment: can you explain why you added var?

Comment: In JavaScript you can (and should) declare variables using the `var` preserved keyword, so that you can store and reuse them in your code. More detailed explanation you might find useful: http://www.wikihow.com/Declare-a-Variable-in-Javascript

Answer (score 0):

**1**- You have an  unterminated string literal at line 34 :

```
x="Heather this is a series of Pitures, Videos, and Poems to show you the 

love that I have for you!"
```

For your script to work, you have to replace the line breaks in your string with "\n" in between "to " and "show". Also, take out the line breaks.

**2**- innerText does not work with Firefox, just use innerHTML all the time instead at line 38 :

```
if (document.getElementById("hheader").innertext == x)
```

**3**- = = makes no sense if you want to assign a value. Use only 1 equal sign when you assign a value to a variable. 
Use two only when you are making an if statement!
    Watch it at :
    line 40 :

```
document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML= =work;
```

and at line 44 :

```
document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML== x
```

**4**- Line 13 has an extra quote at the end that you want to take out :

```
show you the love that I have for you!"
```

If you replace all these mistakes, your script works.
Please look at a modified version of your script that works here:
http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/stackoverflow/2014_01_29/new.html

Or just copy paste this html as is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Head>
<title>Heather I Love You!</title>
</head>
<body style= background-color:#A8A8A8>


<!========This is the header===========>
<div id="header" style= "background-color:#00FF33;" >
<h1><p id="hheader">Heather this is a series of Pitures, Videos, and Poems to 

show you the love that I have for you!</p></h1></div>

<!=============The side bar that will allow a list of where she Wants to 

go==========>

<div id="Menu" Style="background-

color:#660033;height:300px;width:125px;float:left;">
<Talbe>

<b><h3{color:white}>Categories</h3></b><br>
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeHead()">click here!</button><br>



<!--Functions-->
<Script>
function ChangeHead()
{
var g=document.getElementById("hheader")
  x="Heather this is a series of Pitures, Videos, and Poems to \n\nshow you the love that I have for you!"
  work="Here are some pictures of us and the boys"
  if (document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML == x)
    {
    document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML=work; 
    }
  else
    {
    document.getElementById("hheader").innerHTML= x
    }
}
</Script>
</body>

</Html>
```